# better copy-paste multiple lines in visual mode where vim pastes after that visual chunk of code

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

I want to select multiple lines in vim,
copy them, and **paste after that chunk of code (with cursor at the beginning).**

`yp` doesn't work because in visual chunk of code,
vim pastes **after the 1st line of visually selected lines** inside that visual block,
not after the whole visually selected chunk of code.

Is there any better way to do this?

I tried to make an alternative solution on my own
but didn't succeed.

After some workaround, here's my config

```
vmap <silent> <c-l> yP
```

When I press `Ctrl+l`

```
    [cursor-position]for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    }
```

I get this

```
    [cursor-position]for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    }
```

but I want

```
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    }
    [cursor-position]for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << n[i] << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> copy-paste entire block after (not inside the first selected block)
> with cursor at the beginning of 2nd paste

Just <strike>four</strike> three keys

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>